# Position view relative to a another centered view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Hello SwiftUI community,

I'm trying to do something that's probably easy to do but I'm stuck on it since hours. 
In a list, I'd like to have items composed of:

- A text centered horizontaly (a number)
- A text on the left of the number
- A text on the right of the number

[image]

I've tried many things (alignments, aligmentguides, GeometryReader....) but didn't find the way to achieve the result above. Does anyone has an example to help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

A view for List row

```
struct DemoCenteredNumberView: View {
    var value: Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer().overlay(
                Text("Text on left side")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
            )
            Text("\(value)").padding()
            Spacer().overlay(
                Text("Text on right")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            )
        }
    }
}
```